# How can I to use in Laravel 8 custom enum value?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8 I use enum class app/Library/LayoutType.php :

```
<?php namespace App\Library {

    use WBoyz\LaravelEnum\BaseEnum;

    class LayoutType extends BaseEnum
    {
        const ltFrontend = 'frontend';
        const ltAdmin = 'admin';
        const ltPersonal = 'personal';
    }

}
```

based on https://github.com/wboyz/laravel-enum extention.
I try to use it in blade.php file :

```
{!! myMethod('error', LayoutType::ltFrontend) !!}
```

and I have to set lines

```
<?php
use App\Library\LayoutType;
?>
```

in the same blade.php file. I dislike it and try to avoid it,

Method `myMethod` is located in file `app/Library/helper.php`, which is written in `composer.json` as :

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Library/helper.php"
    ],
```

If these is a way to use these enum in blade files? Maybe based on other class, not  WBoyz\LaravelEnum ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either include them as you mentioned, or you specify the whole namespace every time:

```
{!! myMethod('error', \App\Library\LayoutType::ltFrontend) !!}
```